# alternative way, since for_each and count cannot be in same resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp

I've config that need to use count and for_each at the same time.
here's the config block

```
variable "all_zone" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["asia-southeast1-a", "asia-southeast1-b", "asia-southeast1-c"]
}

variable "backends" {
  description = "Map backend indices to list of backend maps."
  type = map(object({
    neg_name  = string
   }))
}

data "google_compute_network_endpoint_group" "get_neg" {
  for_each = var.backends
  count   = length(var.all_zone)
  zone    = var.all_zone[count.index]
  name    = lookup(each.value, "neg_name")
  
}

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "default" {
. . .
dynamic "backend" {
    for_each = [for b in data.google_compute_network_endpoint_group.get_neg[*].id : b]
    content {
      group = backend.value
    }
  }
}
```

is there anyway to do this?

Update: here's sample var.backends

```
backends = {
    default = {
        neg_name = 'name-1'
    }
}
```

**Update: Thanks for @marcin for the solution. but I've another problem to acessing this data.**

Before I use `helper_map`

```
data "google_compute_network_endpoint_group" "get_neg" {
  count   = length(var.all_zone)
  zone    = var.all_zone[count.index]
  name    = 'name-1'
  
}
```

and here structure off the output data:

```
neg = [
      + {
          + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-a/networkEndpointGroups/name-1"
          + name                  = "name-1"
          + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-a"
        },
      + {
          + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-b/networkEndpointGroups/name-1"
          + name                  = "name-1"
          + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-b"
        },
      + {
          + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-c/networkEndpointGroups/name-1"
          + name                  = "name-1"
          + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-c"
        },
    ]
```

here's I accessing the data

```
for_each = [for b in data.google_compute_network_endpoint_group.get_neg[*].id : b]
```

after use `map_helper`

```
neg = [
      + {
          + default-asia-southeast1-a  = {
              + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-a/networkEndpointGroups/k8s1-e051d246-default-gclb-poc-8080-ef51ff1c"
              + name                  = "name-1"
              + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-a"
            }
          + default-asia-southeast1-b  = {
              + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-b/networkEndpointGroups/name-1"
              + name                  = "name-1"
              + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-b"
            }
          + default-asia-southeast1-c  = {
              + id                    = "projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-c/networkEndpointGroups/name-1"
              + name                  = "name-1"
              + zone                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/k8s-playground-public/zones/asia-southeast1-c"
            }
        },
    ]
```

and how i access this `id` of data.

Comment: Why you wouldn't you be able to use `count` and `for_each` in `google_compute_backend_service`? It normally works. What exactly did you do? What errors did you get?

Comment: Hi, i use `count` and `for_each` in `google_compute_network_endpoint_group`
the error like this 
`The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one
should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.`

Comment: Can you please update questions with your code and error messages

Comment: What is example value of `var.backends`?

Comment: I already put all variable in that block of code..and for error message I think no need to put in question, because count and for_each is cannot in same resource
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html
I update the question with some logic

Comment: You are not showing `var.backends`.

Comment: I updated the question, with sample of `var.backends`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve with your data structures, but one way to overcome your issue, would be to create **local helper variable**, which would be the combination of your `backends` and `all_zone`. For example:

```
variable "backends" {

  description = "Map backend indices to list of backend maps."
  
  type = map(object({
    neg_name  = string
   }))
   
   default = {
        default = {
          neg_name = "name-1"
        }
  }
}


variable "all_zone" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["asia-southeast1-a", "asia-southeast1-b", "asia-southeast1-c"]
}

locals {

  helper_map = merge([
          for backend_key, backend_value in var.backends:
            {
              for zone in var.all_zone: 
              "${backend_key}-${zone}" => {
                  backend_value = backend_value.neg_name
                  zone = zone
              }
            }
        ]...)


}
```

which gives:

```
{
  "default-asia-southeast1-a" = {
    "backend_value" = "name-1"
    "zone" = "asia-southeast1-a"
  }
  "default-asia-southeast1-b" = {
    "backend_value" = "name-1"
    "zone" = "asia-southeast1-b"
  }
  "default-asia-southeast1-c" = {
    "backend_value" = "name-1"
    "zone" = "asia-southeast1-c"
  }
}
```

Then, you can easily iterate over this join structure (example only):

```
data "google_compute_network_endpoint_group" "get_neg" {
  for_each = local.helper_map
  zone    = each.value.zone
  name    = each.value.backend_value
  
}
```

The above will probably **require** further adjustment to match your data structures, but the general idea of using local helper variable remains same.

Comment: Hi, thank you, its worked.. but 'ive another problem, how to called that data resource?
before I called the data like this 
`for_each = [for b in data.google_compute_network_endpoint_group.get_neg[*].id : b]`
now the output structure become different

Comment: I updated my question, with the exact output, before and after